# How many Europeans have died fighting for the YPG & YPJ?

Tags: armed-conflict, europe, kurdistan

According to [a March 2018 UK press report](https://www.independent.co.uk/voices/anna-campbell-death-syria-afrin-kurdish-fought-with-ypj-ypg-reaction-a8265176.html), 8 UK citizens (7 men and one woman) have died fighting as volunteers in/alongside the YPG or YPJ.

Are there any similar broader statistics for Europe?

We seem to have [a rough estimate](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/national-security/american-civilians-who-fought-in-kurdish-units-against-isis-watch-a-dream-unravel/2019/10/18/84ce26d6-f100-11e9-b2da-606ba1ef30e3_story.html) how many Westerners are still fighting in that camp:

> Thomas McClure, a British volunteer with the Syrian Kurds, said it is “really hard to say” how many Westerners are still living in Syrian Kurdish enclaves, but estimated it could be more than 100. Some are still part of the Kurdish militias, he said, and scores of others provide medical care and carry out other tasks.

But I guess deaths are easier to count, so is there are combined toll for Europeans and/or Westerners in the YPG/YPJ camp?

Comment: I assume the counting problem is due to the imprecise notion of "European". Quite a few may have lost their citizenship because they joined a terrorist organization.

Comment: @MSalters: has anyone lost it for joining the YPG (as opposed to ISIS)?

Comment: I have no idea. The only thing I know is that possibly our governments consider them terrorists when in reality they are heroes.